# Three.js envmaps and vertex animation

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader

I am making my first steps coding with JavaScript and playing with Three.js.

I am learning how to use Shaders and I have a week stuck with a vertex animation that doesn't work.

This one is my Vertex Shader:

```
uniform float fresnelBias;
uniform float amplitude;
uniform float fresnelScale;
uniform float fresnelPower;
attribute float displacement;

varying float vReflectionFactor;
varying vec3 vReflect;

void main() {
  vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
  vec4 worldPosition = modelMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );

  vec3 worldNormal = normalize( mat3( modelMatrix[0].xyz, modelMatrix[1].xyz, modelMatrix[2].xyz ) * normal );

  vec3 I = worldPosition.xyz - cameraPosition;

  vReflect = reflect( I, worldNormal );
  vReflectionFactor = fresnelBias + fresnelScale * pow( 1.0 + dot( normalize( I ), worldNormal ), fresnelPower );

  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
}
```

and this one is Fragment Shader:

```
uniform vec3 color;
uniform samplerCube envMap;

varying vec3 vReflect;
varying float vReflectionFactor;

void main() {
  vec4 envColor = textureCube( envMap, vec3( -vReflect.x, vReflect.yz ) );
  gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(color, envColor.xyz, vec3(clamp( vReflectionFactor, 0.0, 1.0 ))), 1.0);
}
```

Then I declared a variable to my attributes and another to my uniforms to assign it to a geometry but when I load the site I don't see anything. The JavaScript console tells that in this line `uniforms.amplitude.value = Math.sin(frame);` uniforms is not defined.

Do you have some recomendation? Do you know something that I can do?

I let here my complete code I hope it could help:

```
<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

uniform float fresnelBias;
uniform float amplitude;
uniform float fresnelScale;
uniform float fresnelPower;
attribute float displacement;

varying float vReflectionFactor;
varying vec3 vReflect;

void main() {
  vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
  vec4 worldPosition = modelMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );

  vec3 worldNormal = normalize( mat3( modelMatrix[0].xyz, modelMatrix[1].xyz, modelMatrix[2].xyz ) * normal );

  vec3 I = worldPosition.xyz - cameraPosition;

  vReflect = reflect( I, worldNormal );
  vReflectionFactor = fresnelBias + fresnelScale * pow( 1.0 + dot( normalize( I ), worldNormal ), fresnelPower );

  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
}
  </script>

  <script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

uniform vec3 color;
uniform samplerCube envMap;

varying vec3 vReflect;
varying float vReflectionFactor;

void main() {
  vec4 envColor = textureCube( envMap, vec3( -vReflect.x, vReflect.yz ) );
  gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(color, envColor.xyz, vec3(clamp( vReflectionFactor, 0.0, 1.0 ))), 1.0);
}
  </script>

  <script>

  var camera, scene, renderer;
  var mesh, material, controls, sky;
  init();
  animate();

  function init(){
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
    renderer.setClearColor(0xfffff, 0);
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000);
    camera.position.z = 400;
    //controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var numberOfImages = 46, images = [];
            for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfImages; i++) {
              images.push('sources/instagram2/image' + i + ".jpg");
            }

    var urls = images.sort(function(){return .6 - Math.random()}).slice(0,6);
    var textureCube = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube( urls );
    // Skybox
    var skyshader = THREE.ShaderLib[ "cube" ];
    skyshader.uniforms[ "tCube" ].value = textureCube;

    var skymaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {

      fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent,
      vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
      uniforms: skyshader.uniforms,
      depthWrite: false,
      side: THREE.BackSide

    } );

    sky = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1500, 1500, 1500 ), skymaterial );
    sky.visible = false;
    scene.add( sky );

    var attributes = {
        displacement: {
        type: 'f', // a float
        value: [] // an empty array
        }
    };

    var uniforms = {
        color: {
          type: "c",
          value: new THREE.Color(0x000000),
        },
        envMap: {
          type: "t",
          value: textureCube
        },
        fresnelBias: {
          type: "f",
          value: 0.1
        },
        fresnelScale: {
          type: "f",
          value: 1.0
        },
        fresnelPower: {
          type: 'f',
          value: 2.0
        },
        amplitude: {
          type: 'f',
          value: 0
        }
    };
    var vertexShader = document.getElementById('vertexShader').text;
    var fragmentShader = document.getElementById('fragmentShader').text;
    material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(
        {
          uniforms : uniforms,
          vertexShader : vertexShader,
          fragmentShader : fragmentShader,
        });


    var loader = new THREE.BinaryLoader();
    loader.load( "sources/obj/mmlogo/mm_logo.js", function ( geometry ) {

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.scale.set( 300, 300, 300 );

    var vertices = mesh.geometry.vertices;
    var values = attributes.displacement.value
    for(var v = 0; v < vertices.length; v++) {
    values.push(Math.random() * 10);
    }

    scene.add(mesh);

    } );



    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040 ); // soft white light
    scene.add( light );

    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    directionalLight.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
    scene.add(directionalLight);

    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

  }

  function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  }

  var frame = 0;

  function animate() {

    uniforms.amplitude.value = Math.sin(frame);
    frame += 0.01;

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    //controls.update();
    //mesh.rotation.x += 0.005;
    //mesh.rotation.y += 0.005;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    stats.update();
  }
```

**Update:**

I Added the uniforms variable to the global scope and now the console doesn't show me any problem but I can't see the vertex animation:

```
<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

uniform float fresnelBias;
uniform float amplitude;
uniform float fresnelScale;
uniform float fresnelPower;
attribute float displacement;

varying float vReflectionFactor;
varying vec3 vReflect;

void main() {

  vec3 newPosition = position + normal * vec3(displacement * amplitude);

  vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
  vec4 worldPosition = modelMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );

  vec3 worldNormal = normalize( mat3( modelMatrix[0].xyz, modelMatrix[1].xyz, modelMatrix[2].xyz ) * normal );

  vec3 I = worldPosition.xyz - cameraPosition;

  vReflect = reflect( I, worldNormal );
  vReflectionFactor = fresnelBias + fresnelScale * pow( 1.0 + dot( normalize( I ), worldNormal ), fresnelPower );

  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
}
  </script>

  <script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

uniform vec3 color;
uniform samplerCube envMap;

varying vec3 vReflect;
varying float vReflectionFactor;

void main() {
  vec4 envColor = textureCube( envMap, vec3( -vReflect.x, vReflect.yz ) );
  gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(color, envColor.xyz, vec3(clamp( vReflectionFactor, 0.0, 1.0 ))), 1.0);
}
  </script>

  <script>

  var camera, scene, renderer;
  var mesh, material, controls, sky;

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
    renderer.setClearColor(0xfffff, 0);
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000);
    camera.position.z = 400;


    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var numberOfImages = 46, images = [];
            for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfImages; i++) {
              images.push('sources/instagram2/image' + i + ".jpg");
            }

    var urls = images.sort(function(){return .6 - Math.random()}).slice(0,6);
    var textureCube = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube( urls );

    var skyshader = THREE.ShaderLib[ "cube" ];
    skyshader.uniforms[ "tCube" ].value = textureCube;

    var skymaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {

      fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent,
      vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
      uniforms: skyshader.uniforms,
      depthWrite: false,
      side: THREE.BackSide

    } );

    sky = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1500, 1500, 1500 ), skymaterial );
    sky.visible = false;
    scene.add( sky );

    var attributes = {
        displacement: {
        type: 'f', 
        value: [] 
        }
    };

    var uniforms = {
        color: {
          type: "c",
          value: new THREE.Color(0x000000),
        },
        envMap: {
          type: "t",
          value: textureCube
        },
        fresnelBias: {
          type: "f",
          value: 0.1
        },
        fresnelScale: {
          type: "f",
          value: 1.0
        },
        fresnelPower: {
          type: 'f',
          value: 2.0
        },
        amplitude: {
          type: 'f',
          value: 0
        }
    };
    var vertexShader = document.getElementById('vertexShader').text;
    var fragmentShader = document.getElementById('fragmentShader').text;
    material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(
        {
          uniforms : uniforms,
          vertexShader : vertexShader,
          fragmentShader : fragmentShader,
        });


    var loader = new THREE.BinaryLoader();
    loader.load( "sources/obj/mmlogo/mm_logo.js", function ( geometry ) {

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.scale.set( 100, 100, 100 );

    var vertices = mesh.geometry.vertices;
    var values = attributes.displacement.value
    for(var v = 0; v < vertices.length; v++) {
    values.push(Math.random() * 30);
    }

    scene.add(mesh);

    } );



    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040 );
    scene.add( light );

    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    directionalLight.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
    scene.add(directionalLight);

    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);



  function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  }

  var frame = 0;

  function animate() {

    uniforms.amplitude.value = Math.sin(frame);
    frame += 0.1;

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    //controls.update();
    //mesh.rotation.x += 0.005;
    //mesh.rotation.y += 0.005;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }

  animate();

  </script>
```

Do you have some conseil to make it?

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the `uniforms` variable in the `init()` function so it's scope is within that function and can not be accessed in the `animate()` function.
Add the `uniforms` variable to the global scope and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you @2pha. By the way I found your experiments in the web http://blog.2pha.com/experimenting-threejs-shaders-and-shadermaterial and they are really helpful.

Comment: I will update my question to show the code without any console error. Now I can see my model but It doesn't make the vertex animation. Do you have some conseil?

Comment: make a jsfiddle of it so it is easier to help you

Comment: I tried to make a jsfiddle but it doesn't load correctly. I load it here http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=75645787875067994787 for the moment. I hope you can take a look and give me some recommendation.

Comment: Take a look [HERE](http://blog.2pha.com/using-threejs-jsfiddle) for implementing three.js in jsfiddle. Make a fiddle with the most basic code that demonstrates your problem and use a sphere or box as your mesh rather than trying to load one. People are not going to download your files as it just isn't worth the effort. If you want help, you have to make it easy for people to give help.

Comment: Hello @2pha and thank you again for that link. This is a cube that I made from one of your shader experiments http://jsfiddle.net/gnazoa/z4v449kh/1/ I tryied to animate it using code from this tutorial https://aerotwist.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-shaders-part-2/ but I can't see the vertex animation. Do you have some conseil? Thank you

Comment: Are you just trying to animate vertices? If so, you have a lot of stuff in your fiddle that is not needed and potentially confusing. I suggest you create a very basic scene such as [this one](http://blog.2pha.com/demos/threejs/shaders/single_color.html) and then just add the vertices animation code.

Comment: I am trying to learn how to animate vertices using your experiment because I like the Fresnel Cubemap reflection. For the moment I know how to animate the vertices with a really basic scene like this one https://aerotwist.com/static/tutorials/an-introduction-to-shaders-part-2/demo/demo-6.html but when I try to apply it in your experiment I don't see anything http://jsfiddle.net/gnazoa/z4v449kh/1/

Comment: @Gabriel Nazoa. The aerotwist example uses R41 of THREE.js.  Your jsfiddle uses the latest release.  In a recent release (R72) of THREE.js the attribute methods changed as per [this documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/api/materials/ShaderMaterial.html).  That may be where your problem lies.  Maybe you can try working in Chrome where you can at least get error messages in the console.